# Excel VBA multiple loops based on columns

Tags: excel, vba

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orikE.png)

I have a lots of price data but want to analyse it in terms or a hourly price divided by a weekly average (week being Sunday to Sunday) for a few years.
Basically in 'column L' i'm trying to get a coefficient (hourly price divided by weekly average) were the average has been separated into peak hours (between 0800 and 2100) and off peak hours (all other hours) - an average for peak and an average for off peak.

Here is my code but i'm really new to VBA and this is not right, not sure how to fix it:

```
Sub averagehourprice()
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim t As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For t = 2012 To 2016 'for each year loop
Range ("B2:B43135")


    For x = 1 To 52 'for each week loop
    Range ("D2:D43135")

        For y = 1 To 24 'for each hour in each week loop
        Range ("F2:F43135")

        'create a coulmn of peak hours and off peak hours
        If Range("F2:F43135") > 8 And Range("F2:F43135") < 21 Then Range("H2:H43135") = 1
        'if each cell value in the range is "F2:F43135" >8 and < than 21 then coresspondinbg cell in H =1 else 0
        Else: Range "H2:H43135" = "-"
        End If
        'if a cell in H is "-" then cell in I = 1
        If Range("H2:H43135") = "-" Then Range("I2:I43135") = 1
        Else: Range("I2:I43135") = "-"
        End If

        'get weekly average of peak values and weekly average of off peak values
        Range("J2:J43135") = Sum((Range("G2:G43135")) * (Range("H2:H43135"))) / Sum((Range("H2:H43135")))
        Range("K2:K43135") = Sum((Range("G2:G43135")) * (Range("I2:I43135"))) / Sum((Range("I2:I43135")))

        'create a coeffieicent as a function of day price and average weekly price

        Range("L2:L43135") = Range("G2:G43135") / Range("J2:J43135") + Range("G2:G43135") / Range("K2:K43135")

        Next y
    Next x
Next t

End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What specifically is your issue? Code has a bug? The output is not what you expect?

Comment: Hi, Basically it says Sub or Function not defined, I have looked this up but feel that I have defined everything I need. I think the issue is around attributing the for loops to a specific set of cells . For example I want to loop though Column B  for each year (2012,2013..) the move onto each week in that year. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't understand completely how to  use loops. The purpose of a loop is that you have a variable that needs to be used in a function. You specify a variable but you don't use it. See this link for more information: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

what you exactly want to do with the loop is not totaly clear to me. Maybe if you can explain your question a little bit more extensively for me I can create something for you to work with

PS: This should be in the comment and not as Answer, but I don't have enough rep to comment

I have the following for you. The macro beneath will give you the average price per week for each year. If you lable column I as 2012, J as 2013...... then in this column will appear for week 1 to 52 the average price in that week.

paste this in a module and change the sheetname, then run it:

```
Sub averageperweek()

For i = 2 To 43145
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "2012" Then Column = 9
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "2013" Then Column = 10
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "2014" Then Column = 11
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "2015" Then Column = 12
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "2016" Then Column = 13

Row = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value + 1

Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, Column).Value = (Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, Column).Value + Sheets("sheet1").Range("G" & i).Value) / 168

Next i

End Sub
```

Looking at your screenshot, it appears that your week numbers are not correct. At 2 jan your week number also goes to 2.

hope this will help you, and if you need more help don't hesitate to ask

Comment: I want to loop through each year, then each week in each year, and create an average value for the series, column G, (prices) for each week depending on whether the hour price is 'peak' or 'off peak'. I then want to compare each given hour and divide it by the average for the week the hour is in.

Comment: The screenshot I took of my excel page may help (it's at the top)